# Clearity on github structure for terraform template

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-automation-manager

I am trying to understand the readymade template for IBM Cloud at `https://cam-proxy-ng.ng.bluemix.net/cam/instances/#!/deployTemplateEditorWithNoParam/7921d773a240309379cf2c31c8004c9a`

which is `Node.js on a Single VM`.

When we go to the source code at git referred in this template `https://github.com/camc-experimental/terraform-modules/blob/master/ibmcloud/virtual_guest/` there is a `createVirtualGuest.tf` file. I am trying to understand why the create virtual guest is on GIT and not on the .tf template on bluemix console? Why there are 2 files which as code for creation of virtual guest?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the structure of a Terraform template. You can define fragments of a resource orchestration in so-called modules, which are stored as separate files, and then refer to them from within the template.

The way the CAM service currently works, you can only work on the master template within the service. Modules that are referenced cannot be edited in the service and are pulled in from Github.

This is not ideal, and it should allow browsing and editing modules, too, but that function is currently not supported.